# Implementing Whatsapp Business APIs using gupshup.io platform

Tags: whatsapp, gupshup

gupshup.io provides a way to utilise whatsapp business by exposing a single api interface. I am exploring it. But the documentation is poor. 
I wonder how the entire conversation can be tied together. Is there any session that is initiated when the message exchange begins? The official site suggests to use Stack Overflow as forum and hence the question.

Comment: Are you trying to use Gupshup's access API? Can you share the API URL?

Answer (score 0):

For every new client (business phone number) a new WhatsApp Business API client (docker containers) is started. This is uniquely tied to the databases. Just like everything stored in your phone WhatsApp app is stored in the databases, the docker containers are tied closely to the database to create a unique session for you and store the messages. 
The documentation at [WhatsApp Official Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/) can give you more information.

Answer (score 0):

1. Login to gupshup.io [WhatsApp dashboard](https://www.gupshup.io/developer/whatsapp-api)
2. Click ‘+’ Icon to create a App and select the type of app: Access API
   [image]
3. You will see a Sandbox: 
   Set up a callback URL where you can receive incoming messages from your users and for outgoing messages to user, use the sandbox API.
   [image]